# Codeigniter routes are not show anything

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm dealing with a codeigniter app that I haven't developed and  is not working , if I request the main url  the main controller is not called(and every route I've tried gets an 404 error), the browser shows the directory listed.

Another project on the same server with codeigniter without any changes works correctly,

Anyone know what could be the problem??

Comment: have u set base_url in config.php, show your code

Comment: yes, base_url is setted

Comment: can you post code of route file?

Comment: Is not a code problem ,the app works on the server ,but is not possible to make it work on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the project folder in the `base_url` like below

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/project_folder/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and, update your `.htaccess` file with this code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```